# How do I make Unity halt on exceptions?

Tags: unity

I'm trying to debug a Unity project using the Unity Editor and Visual Studio. A runtime exception keeps popping up, but the debugger doesn't halt when an exception occurs, making it impossible to debug my code efficiently.

In Visual Studio, I've gone into Tools -> Options -> Tools For Unity and set "Exception Support" to "True". I've also enabled *all* types of exceptions in the Exception Settings panel. I am connecting the debugger to Unity using the "Attach to Unity" button. Breakpoints are working, but the debugger isn't halting on Exceptions.

What do I need to do to get Unity/VS to actually halt on Exceptions?

Note: I've tried closing and re-opening both Unity and VS many times but that doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 13):

[This documentation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-tools-for-unity-2-0-preview-2/) on the 2.0 Unity tools preview for VS implies you have to both enable Unity exception support via `Tools -> Options -> Tools For Unity` (setting "exception support" to true, as you've done) *and* enable the appropriate CLR exception masks in Visual Studio's built-in [exception settings window](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/the-new-exception-settings-window-in-visual-studio-2015/) (check the box next to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions").

For best result you may want to check and then un-check the CLR exceptions tick, as that will ensure *all* the exception subtypes are enabled to get started with.

Answer (score 5):

I think,  a quick solution, you can try: Write an error log in exception block of the code

```
Debug.LogError("Exception occured");
```

And before running the editor open console and hit **Error Pause** in the console log.
[image]

The game will pause as any error occurred in the console.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to do a couple more things to get this working. In my case, I wanted Unity's built-in Assertions to raise exceptions that would be caught by VS. I had to do the following to make this happen.

1. Configure Unity's Assert class to raise exceptions via `Assert.raiseExceptions=true`
2. Add the specific type of Exception to VS's exception settings window. (Right click, select Add, and input `UnityEngine.Assertions.AssertionException`)

Comment: Are there any other steps you took to get Unity Assertions to throw?  These two steps don't seem to work on Unity 2014 LTS https://answers.unity.com/questions/1581028/debugging-assertion-failed-on-expression-errors.html

Comment: No, however I've been using Unity 2018.x.x. Is it possible that older versions of Unity used a different Assertion type? (In which case, you'd need to add a slightly different qualified typename to that list).

Comment: Additionally, I noticed that in VS Community 15.9.2 - there was a new tickbox in this list for `<All Common Language Runtime Exceptions not in this list>` (Look under the Common Language Runtime Exceptions` category). If the exceptions you're attempting to catch from within Unity are not actually `AssertionException`'s, then it's possible this tickbox might be inclusive enough to catch what you're after.